# Вылетает ошибка на Android 8.0

Tags: android

На всех версиях Android всё работает как надо, а на Android 8.0 вылетает приложение и выдаёт такую ошибку и ссылается на layout и именно на XWalkView:

```
 Process: com.hodite.com.shcherbuk, PID: 1778
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hodite.com.shcherbuk/com.hodite.com.shcherbuk.WebActivity.WebActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.hodite.com.shcherbuk.WebActivity.WebActivity.onCreate(WebActivity.java:55)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{da07273 1778:com.hodite.com.shcherbuk/u0a68} (pid=1778, uid=10068) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
    at org.xwalk.core.ReflectConstructor.newInstance(ReflectConstructor.java:54)
    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.reflectionInit(XWalkView.java:1882)
    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.<init>(XWalkView.java:305)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.hodite.com.shcherbuk.WebActivity.WebActivity.onCreate(WebActivity.java:55) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{da07273 1778:com.hodite.com.shcherbuk/u0a68} (pid=1778, uid=10068) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
    at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.registerContentObserver(IContentService.java:768)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1924)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1913)
    at org.xwalk.core.internal.extension.api.contacts.Contacts.<init>(Contacts.java:42)
    at org.xwalk.core.internal.extension.BuiltinXWalkExtensions.load(BuiltinXWalkExtensions.java:51)
    at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewInternal.initXWalkContent(XWalkViewInternal.java:464)
    at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.<init>(XWalkViewBridge.java:76)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at org.xwalk.core.ReflectConstructor.newInstance(ReflectConstructor.java:48)
```

Как вы уже поняли, я юзаю библу XWalkView, с помощью которой прогружаю сайт.
В чём может быть проблема?

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hodite.com.shcherbuk"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 15
        versionName "0.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: android.permission.READ_CONTACTS и android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS забыли

Comment: Покажите свой `build.gradle`

Comment: @Barmaley добавил

Comment: @Suvitruf добавил, но это не помогло

Comment: @shcherbuk новый лог покажите. В предыдущем логе у вас была ошибка `SecurityException requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS`. Сейчас её быть не должно. Что теперь за ошибка?

Comment: @Suvitruf спасибо) Нашёл решение проблемы, нужно было быблиотеку ручками обновить, ибо она почему-то не подсвечивалась у меня, мол устарела. Поменял версию библы и всё заработало)

Answer (score 1):

Ребята, всё оказалось очень просто.
Нужно было обновить версию библиотеки и всё)
Всем спасибо за помощь)